# Interactive Brokers - Free Trial - Error Code 354 - Requested market data is not subscribed

Tags: interactive-brokers

After running the following code:

```
//IB's main object
var ibClient = new EWrapperExt(this);

//Connect
ibClient.ClientSocket.eConnect("127.0.0.1", 7496, 0);

var contractAAPL = new Contract
{
    Symbol = "AAPL",
    SecType = "STK",
    Currency = "USD",
    Exchange = "Smart"
};

//Invoke IB's ClientSocket's data request
ibClient.ClientSocket.reqMktData(1, contractAAPL, "", false, null);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error. Id: 1, Code: 354, Msg: Requested market data is not subscribed.Error&BEST/STK/Top&BEST/STK/Top
```

I am using the Interactive Brokers (IB) free trial account. Is there something else I need to do with my code or do I actually have to pay IB for this sort of market data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I spoke with IB technical support.

In order to get data from NASDAQ outside of the Trader Workstation using the IB API you need to have a paid subscription to NASDAQ.